# VS Code not showing Static Methods for Abstract Classes with Import Prefix in Dart

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

In Dart:
let "Abstrata" a abstract class:

```
 class Abstrata {
  static metodo() {
    print("hello");
  }
}
```

and in other file we import and use this class!
if we import in the simple way all things go right!
And we can use **Abstrada.metodo()**

The problem is when the import use prefix like **import "x" as y**;

```
import 'package:test/abstrata.dart' as $abs;

teste() {
  $abs.Abstrata.metodo();
}
```

The vscode do not show any static methods for the abstract class when the class is imported with prefix (**$abs**).
You have to know the name and parameters of the method that you want to use **otherwise vscode do not show the statics methods**.

My question is: there is a way to fix this and guide vscode to show **static methods** of **abstract classes** that are **imported using prefix**?

Comment: If you make a typedef then it will work again. But of course this isn't always convenient

Comment: You're probably better off asking this in an issue on the github page for the dart vscode plugin. https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code

Comment: Perhaps related to https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/4794.  I think it happens with any `static` method; I don't think the class being `abstract` is relevant.